# Unable to redirect to detail page through Autolaunched flow

Tags: visual-workflow

We are having a button on Account and once I click on the button, Account will be updated through flow (We also have an **Auto Launched flow** that will update Account). Now once the Account is updated through flow, the flow should redirected back to Account detail page.

I am able to update Account through Auto Launched flow on button click but unable to redirect the screen back to Account detail.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set retURL parameter in the flow url(button). Please refer to below article for more details:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_internal_url_retURL.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you for the reply Manuj. Here problem is that it's auto launched flow which is not having finish behavior so cant set retURL

Comment: Can you save the flow as screen flow and then use the new URL? You can do the update in a screen flow without using screen element.